# Compile code without showing console window

Tags: vb.net, compilation

I have created a simple compiler that will compile VB.net code. It works fine except that a console window always shows up when I compile code. Is there any way to stop the console window from showing up when I compile code? Here is my code:

```
Dim Parameters As New CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters

    Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
    Parameters.GenerateExecutable = True
    Parameters.OutputAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Program"

    Dim Results As CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults = CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VisualBasic").CompileAssemblyFromSource(Parameters, txtEditor.Text)

    If Results.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("There are some errors in the code.")
    Else
        Process.Start(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Program")
    End If
```

And this is the code I am compiling:

```
Public Module Module1

Public Sub Main()
    Dim TestForm As New System.Windows.Forms.Form
    TestForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub 
End Module
```

Comment: Is it a Console type project?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thinking about it, it is probably a Console project. Is there a way to change the type of project?

Comment: On the project properties, on the Application ply, look for Application type.

Comment: Probably easiest to just start over with a non console project and copy this chunk of code across - changing the output type is probably possible but I don't gurantee it will alter the Main so as to properly start the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default target type for CodeDOM is a console application.  For a WinForm application add:

```
Parameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe"
```

see: [target:winexe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/target)